# How do you graph responses in limesurvey v2.05?

Tags: limesurvey

I can see it mentioned in the LimeSurvey manual [https://manual.limesurvey.org/Statistics#Graphs], but this seems to be for an earlier version of  LimeSurvey, not the one I'm using.

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions; you might have better luck trying [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks very much. The question didn't quite fit here, but I didn't know where else to ask it.